# It there a way to add a pipeline to a cmdlet conditionally/dynamically?

Tags: powershell

In PowerShell,
How I can add a pipeline command dynamically/conditionally?

For example,
I have something like this:

If (some condition)
{
   Get-Content $FilePath **| Out-String**
}
else
{
  Get-Content $FilePath 
}

the question is how to add the "| Out-String" without writing the whole IF statement as above?
Maybe we can use some inline IIF statement and etc?

like : Get-Content $FilePath if(true) { |Out-String}

Thanks

Comment: If you're going to use Out-String you need a variable on the left of Get-FileContent, e.g., $x = Get-FileContent $FilePath | Out-String. IMHO you're best sticking with a standard If-then-else construct as it will do what you want and be understandable when you read it vs generating some convoluted one-liner that no one will understand, maybe not even you 6 months from now.

Comment: You can't make up your own syntax for languages. You are bound to the language constructs. Shortcuts do not improve yo code, nor make it understandable, nor make it more maintainable. You have to write code with the understanding that others can / will have to maintain it when you are gone, for whatever reason. PowerShell is verbose for a reason. Easy to read, update, and maintain.

Comment: also that first code line your proposed makes no sense at all.
You are asking for content from a specific path only if it meets come condition.
Else if it doesn't, the read the content from that path which returned nothing in the first place.
that is not a thing. If it does not exist, then why ask for it again.

Comment: I think you want to do this: `Get-Content $FilePath | ForEach-Object { if($True) {$_ | Out-String} }`

Comment: You probably don't need out-string.

Answer (score 1):

The closest you will get to what you are after is this.

```
if (some condition) { Get-Content $FilePath | Out-String } else { Get-Content $FilePath }
```

... is not this...

```
Get-Content $FilePath if(true) { }
```

... .but this...

```
If ($FileContent = Get-Content -Path 'D:\temp\abc.txt')
{$FileContent | Out-String}
```